# How to hide options in a dropdown using select2 plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

We are populating the options in a dropdown through list.The values are added in a list in Action class.
When option is equal to a particular value , we want to hide it.

Following is the code:

```
if (stuval.substring(0, 7) == "<option") {  
   $('#stuclass option:not(:first)').remove(); 
   $('#stuclass').find('option').end().append($(stuval));
}
```

How to hide the option when value is 'Not apply'?

We are using select2 plugin.Tried with following code in CSS.

```
.select2-results [data-select2-id*="not apply"]{
  display : none;
 }
```

Problem with this code is it is removing 'not apply' option from all the dropdowns in the page.Requirement is how to apply for that dropdown(using id).Option should be hidden but not remoed or disabled.Kindly help

HTML Code :

```
<tr>
                                <td><b><bean:message
                                            key="label.stuclass" />:</b></td>
                                <td><html:select property="stuclass" style="text-transform: uppercase;background-color: #A5A5A5;"
                                        styleId="stuclass">
                                <html:option value=""><bean:message key="label.stuclass.select" /></html:option>
                                <html:optionsCollection name="studentForm" property="stuList"  label="label" value="value" />
                                </html:select></td>
                            </tr>
                        
                        While Jquery loading :
                        
                        $("#stuclass").select2({ width: '150px'});
```

Other Dropdown which has 'not apply' as one of its options:(values are loaded into this dropdown in backend through action class)

```
                        $("#stuStatusSearch").select2({ width: '150px'});
                        
                        

<html:select property="stuStatusSearch" styleId="stuStatusSearch">
                                <html:option value=""><bean:message key="label.stuStatusSearch.select" />
                                </html:option><html:optionsCollection name="studentForm" property="stuStatusList" label="label" value="value" />
                            </html:select>
```

Comment: show more codes .

Comment: Edited question. Dropdown options Im seeting in Backend. Requirement is have to hide for that particular value based on dropdown value. Kindly help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use templateResult: its the solution to select what options you want to show/or hide. In this sample, i dont want to show Apple, Cat and ViewExposure.

```js
$("#example").select2({
    templateResult: function(option, container) {
        if ($(option.element).attr("data-select2-id") == "not apply"){ 
          $(container).css("display","none");
        }

        return option.text;
    }
});
```

```css
//put this line in css file  to avoid empty line in search
//not necessary with templateResult
/*
li.select2-results__option:empty {
    display: none;
}
*/
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id="example" multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px">
    <option data-select2-id='not apply' value="1">Apple</option>
    <option value="Bat">Bat</option>
    <option data-select2-id='not apply' value="Cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="Dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="Elephant">Elephant</option>
    <option data-select2-id='not apply' value="ViewExposure">ViewExposure</option>
    <option value="DummyData">Dummy - Data</option>
    <option value="Dummy-Data">Dummy-Data</option>
    <option value="Dummy:Data">Dummy:Data</option>
    <option value="Dummy(Data)">Dummy(Data)</option>    
</select>

  </body>
</html>
```

The Html generated: you could see the display none on the the first option

```
<ul class="select2-results__options" role="listbox" aria-multiselectable="true" id="select2-example-results" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false">
  <li class="select2-results__option select2-results__option--selectable" id="select2-example-result-u9nt-1" role="option" data-select2-id="select2-data-select2-example-result-u9nt-1" aria-selected="false" style="display: none;">Apple</li>
  <li class="select2-results__option select2-results__option--selectable" id="select2-example-result-9nwy-Bat" role="option" data-select2-id="select2-data-select2-example-result-9nwy-Bat" aria-selected="false">Bat</li>
   :
  <li class="select2-results__option select2-results__option--selectable" id="select2-example-result-eazj-Dummy(Data)" role="option" data-select2-id="select2-data-select2-example-result-eazj-Dummy(Data)" aria-selected="false">Dummy(Data)</li>
</ul>
```

The Html is generated each time you open the dropdown...

Comment: How to hide dropdown option using id in Select2.Code you provided hides option in all the dropdowns in that page.

Comment: show me your different dropdown in your html code..

Comment: you can use #id instead the class, see my answer modified

Comment: why not display the html code generated in the page html? that 's will be easier to see your problem

Comment: Using #id it is not working....Can you please suggest me some other way?Option is not getting disabled when I use ID..

Comment: i have forgotten the tag option, because i suppose the `not apply` is on option?   test my answer moidified

Comment: one question, with select2 i am pretty sure to put display:none  or hide on option dont avoid to see the search tag..is it what you want because its not the same problem

Comment: Instead of  data-select2-id='not apply' ..requirement is to hide the option when value='not apply'...How to achieve this..kindly help..

Comment: $("#stuclass option[data-select2-id*='not apply']").hide(); is not working for select2 dropdowns....

Comment: @padmaja have you tested the solution?